# Best way to save orders in array by date

Tags: php, mysql

My database is: table: orders, columns: id (int), order_status(varchar), time (timestamp), price (decimal);

I want to receive the sum of all orders prices by each day in one array. What is the best way to do that?

I've used this, but it get lasts 24h, 48h, 72h... orders and not by each day (from 00:00 until 23:59).

```
$TimeBack = time() - 86400;
$Time = time();
$month = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++){
//query just for example
$month[$i] = SELECT FROM orders WHERE `order_status` = 'Completed' AND `time` BETWEEN {$TimeBack} AND {$Time} ORDER BY `id` ASC");
$TimeBack = $TimeBack - 86400;
$Time = $Time - 86400;
}
```

Comment: `select ... where date(time) = curdate() - interval 1 day`, `... - interval 2 day`, etc...

Comment: Marc, maybe it work just for datetime, no? It returns nothing here.